# management using MB @ViewScoped

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2

```
//exemple01
@ManagedBean(name = "mb")
@ViewScoped
public class ExempleMB implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{serviceBO}")
private ServiceBO serviceBO;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init{
 list= serviceBO.list();
 }

public void query(){
  serviceBO.query(parameters); 
 }
}
```

Exemple 01:
Thus returns me the error
javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.NotSerializableException: being that it can not be serialized because he and managed by spring.

```
//exemple02
@ManagedBean(name = "mb")
@ViewScoped
public class ExempleMB implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{serviceBO}")
private transient ServicoBO serviceBO;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init{
 list= serviceBO.list();
 }

public void query(){
  servicoBO.query(paramestros); 
 }
}
```

Exemple 02:
He makes the query init, however the method this null search service, as it has to be marked as transient as this, how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Make your `ServiceBO` class implements the `Serializable` interface...

Comment: I faced similar problem, I used aop for interceptor one of the spring class involved in that chain is not Serializable. To solve that I used the following context param. 
`<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>server</param-value>
 </context-param>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring services are not serializable. You could instead inject *fully serializable proxies*, so that `@ViewScoped` bean serialization would happen flawlessly.

If you're using annotations, just add the following to your class definition:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "singleton", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public YourService { ... }
```

If you're using xml, do the following:

```
<bean id="yourService" class="your.package.YourServiceImpl" scope="singleton">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
    ...
</bean>
```